# Slow execution with POST cURL request

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL request that is giving me a 411 length required error if execute without the Content-Length header. When I add `$header[] = 'Content-Length: 0` to my array of headers, it is executed slowly (~15sec.).

I use the same code on a different domain without any problem. On this domain, I don't need to set the content-length header and I don't receive a 411 error. I'm thinking the Content-Length error might be related to the issue since only a PUT request should give me this error.

This is my current cURL request:

```
$curl = curl_init();

$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic 123123';
$header[] = 'Accept: text/xml';
//$header[] = 'Content-Length: 0';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
```

Edit:
I've changed my `CURLOPT_URL` and added `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

instead of

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url . $data);
```

This way I was able to eliminate the need for a `Content-Length` header but the request is still terribly slow.

Comment: Any sane server will ignore any body you send (and probably disconnect you immediately after it reads your headers for sending an invalid HTTP request) with a `Content-Length: 0` header. `Content-Length: 0` is telling the server you're finished sending the message after the headers. My best guess is that server **believes you when you tell it there's no more coming.** When you subsequently send it malformed headers (your entity body) it's freaking out. You can't do HTTP if you don't follow the protocol.

Comment: This issue has been corrected. The Content-Length header wasn't required for this request. The issue was with the API server where the TTL was too low. We fixed it in our host file and the request has a regular execution speed now.

Answer (score 0):

Some servers require you to set the content length, others don't. This is mainly used so it can base it's buffer on that.

You shouldn't add 0 as content length, but the amount of data that will be sent. If you set it as 0, some servers will refuse to load it.

What I'm guessing is happening is because you set it to 0, it'll read the content byte / byte which is obviously very slow.

Comment: The content-length should only be required for PUT request which is why I thought it was strange for a POST request to give me this error. I've been able to make PUT request with `content-length: 0` and they weren't as slow. However, the 411 error has been corrected when I changed my `CURLOPT_URL` and added a `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option. It seems the issue is within the server since it's working correctly when used on a different server.

Comment: @oliboon You argue it's a server issue but you are actually required to do so by the standards.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness in curl CLI appears to be caused by the HTTP header `Expect: 100-continue` that curl sends in POST requests.

To disable it, use `curl -H "Expect:"` before passing the other arguments.